# How did people describe the frequency of a wave before Hertz?

Tags: physics

It is actually quite strange that the unit of frequency was defined so later. How did people like Newton, Lagrange describe the frequency of a harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Frequency was measured in oscillations per second, before this unit was named after Hertz.

Comment: cf. [“Cycles” to “Hertz”: Why the shift circa 1970?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5552/232)

Answer (score 2):

In 1687 in Principia, Newton mentioned a pendulum "vibrating four times in a second".([link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=lSoJ2tJKfIEC&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=newton%20vibrating-four-times-in-a-second&source=bl&ots=PxtsezQRLh&sig=XAdjYG9-yjS874hHtFYrX6wWwHk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0taC92efSAhXFPBQKHfuhDpAQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=newton%20vibrating-four-times-in-a-second&f=false)) Fractional values were allowed: in 1686, Molyneux mentioned that a "pendulum 39.0 inches long vibrates 60 times in a minute, and 15 hundreds of a vibration more than 60 times".([link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=YYsPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP65&lpg=PP65&dq=%2215%20hundreds%20of%20a%20vibration%20more%20than%2060%22&source=bl&ots=1lDnQrXdnX&sig=47GtICZf00i8y6GjRIJXILLt_iE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUjfjs3efSAhXB8RQKHausDo8Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%2215%20hundreds%20of%20a%20vibration%20more%20than%2060%22&f=false))